# Is this expressed correctly?

Tags: american-english, writing, writing-advice

I have been directed here, so I hope that this question is allowed.

I need English feedback on this sentence about computer programming, please.
I'm helping a friend in Poland with his résumé, but I do not have a background in computer programming, and his English is not fluent. He would like to add the below sentence to his résumé and is asking if it makes sense in English/Computer Science-ese. Again, it's not my background, so I would like to ask anyone with a programming background if the following sentence makes sense and is written correctly in English:

*Software integration and data integration expert who builds and provides solutions successfully embedded in customer systems and processes.*

Thank you!

Comment: Andrea, we don't do proofreading I'm afraid. Please don't simply repost a question which has previously been closed. There's [help available](/help/on-topic): scroll down to "How do I ask about checking my text?"

Comment: The person who closed my question in another tag suggested posting my question here. That's why I reposted it after he closed my previous posting.